# How can I invoke a variable method on a struct

Tags: go

I want to invoke a variable method on a struct like this example

```
type controller struct{}

func (c *controller) Index() {
    fmt.Println("index controller")
}

func invokeIt(action string) {
   (&controller{}).action    // don't work duh
   (&controller{})["action"] // this is Go not js
   // how can I invoke it? 
}
```

thx for the replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DHH, are you porting Rails to Go :) ?

Jokes aside, this is exactly what [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) is for. For example:

```
type Foo struct{}

func (Foo) FooM() { fmt.Println("Foom") }

func main() {
    foo := Foo{}
    reflect.ValueOf(foo).MethodByName("FooM").Call(nil)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/5ZGwlHLEmj

**EDIT:** A more idiomatic way to do it would be to use interfaces, (as someone else had proposed, but then have deleted their answer). So if you want to, say, define something that can do CRUD, in Go you'd usually go with

```
type Resources interface {
    Index()
    New()
    Show(id int)
    // ...
}
```

And maybe an `Invoke` method in order to invoke non-standard methods on this thing using `reflect` like above. `reflect` is very powerful and also a good way to shoot yourself in the foot, so it's never a good idea to overuse it.

Comment: @chendesheng yes, your code seems exactly like what OP would like to have.

Comment: is there also a way how i can instanciate a variable from a package. like controller := var["controller"]. c := controllers["controller"]?